# What is the correct syntax for key value pair in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```
var schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    polls: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'}]
    /*This is incorrect*/votes: [{{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'},{type: number}}]
});
```

Comment: If the site mentions your question could use more body, then please read [ask] on how you can put something meaningful in that body, instead of abusing markup and simply copying your title into your question.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well, I don't know what else there is to say :/ It's just a syntax question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give your `votes` field meaningful structure, use an array of objects instead of value pairs (which can't be strictly defined in Mongoose):

```
votes: [{
    poll: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Poll'},
    count: {type: number}
}]
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the answer ! Would you like to also try to answer this one ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44052804/how-to-check-that-a-user-has-already-voted-on-a-poll